# Storing data from angular.run in any controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I have a function that is triggered when my page is loaded and i get the data

```
    app.run
    (function ($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, PAGES_PERMISSION, AuthService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
          if(!AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
            var userStorage = localStorage.getItem("user_id");
            if(userStorage != null){
              // I want to store userData on my $scope as currentUser
              var usedData = AuthService.isLogged(userStorage);
            }

    app.factory('AuthService', function ($http, $rootScope,Session, AUTH_EVENTS) {
      var authService = {};

     authService.isLogged = function (userId) {
      return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: API_ROOT_SERVER_ADDRESS + "/isLogged",
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            data : {userId : userId}
        }).then(function successCallback(res) {
      Session.create(res.data.student_id, r      es.data.user_name,res.data.profile);
      return res.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("errorCallback in response");
    });
  };

  return authService;
})

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $rootScope,$routeParams, 
LoginService, $location, $window, $http, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {

  $scope.user = {
        username: "",
        password : ""
      };

    $scope.login = function (user) {
    AuthService.login(user).then(function (user) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
      $scope.setCurrentUser(user);
    }, function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    });
  };


});
```

now i want to store userData (or res.data in AuthService) in my $scope, but the only place i can manipulate $scope is on my controllers according to my research. I tried to inject $scope and LoginContorller to my factory and app.run and got there errors:

LoginControllerProvider <- LoginController <- AuthService

Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

How can i store the value that came from my request in my $scope since my call is triggered from app.run and not from any controller as usual?

Comment: You should do the opposite: inject `AuthService` in the controller

Comment: @k102 I already have it injected. I just edited my question with my controller. How can i store the value that came from AuthService on my controller?

Comment: `var usedData = AuthService.isLogged(userStorage);` looks strange. I'd store `userData` indide of the service, so it can be accessed from the controller and then passed to scope.

Comment: AuthService.isLogged(userStorage); will return data from my API. Could u show me how may i store it on the service and retrieve from LoginCtrl?

Comment: Just add a field and getter/setter for it. Set data inside `isLogged`

Comment: Can't you store it in `localStorage` or `cookies`? And retrieve that data in controller and load it into scope variable?

Comment: Thanks for you advice @Chinni i managed to solve it with services only.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the comments from @k102 and managed to solve my problem adding the fragments of code bellow:

1- Created getters and setters in my AuthService 
2- Set the data after my API request
3- Applied the value on my scope from controller

```
  //AuthService setters
  authService.setData = function(data){
    this.authData = data;
    console.log(this.authData);
  }

  authService.getData = function(){
    console.log(this.authData);
    return this.authData;
  }

  //AuthService request
  then(function successCallback(res) {
      authService.setData(res.data);

 //LoginController
 $scope.setCurrentUser(AuthService.getData());
```